# Cython compilation has suddenly started failing

Tags: python, ubuntu, cython

I have a cythonised application which until yesterday was compiling and running completely fine.

Now, suddenly, when trying to compile (Ubuntu 20 server running on DigitalOcean) I get this:

```
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/var/www/anagami_console/anagami/anagamienv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c event.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/event.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The same code compiles and runs perfectly on my windows desktop using python 3.9.

The error message I get is not particularly informative, so I am really not sure where to even look

Comment: Searching for the "Killed signal terminated program cc1" error message suggests that gcc has run out of memory. Maybe split it into smaller parts that your can compile separately?

Comment: hm, that's really weird - the application is pretty lightweight - only about 10k loc, it event compiles and runs fine on my other 10 year old pc.

Comment: @DavidW what seems to have fixed it is deleting all the cython files and recompiling completely fresh - am unsure why the original error happened in the first place but seems to be working now (although compilation is super slow)

Comment: @erixliechtenstein feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 1):

Way to fix it was to delete every single .c and .pyd file and recompile fresh. I'm still not sure what was causing the original error - but deleting + doing a completely fresh recompile fixed it